# iOS 13 viewWillAppear not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios13

I am seeing a strange behavior on iOS 13 beta 6 when project is built with XCode 11 beta. After presenting a view controller (style 'Show' animated as specified in Storyboard) in full screen and dismissing, viewWillAppear on presenting view controller is not called. Is there a change in behavior?

Edit: The workaround of overriding presentationControllerDidDismiss(_:) mentioned in duplicate question did not help me. It's not even called when dismissing a view controller that was presented via a Segue.